# Getting noactivityfound to handle intent error android

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I am making an app where user will be able to add any url as a bookmark. In my main activity once the user clicks a button, i am starting another activity.

```
protected void BookMark(){


            if(check){
            Intent intent=new Intent(this, getURL.class);
//          EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
//              String message= "Fill";
//              intent.putExtra("Value", message);
                startActivity(intent);


            }else  {

                Uri url2=Uri.parse(url1);
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Trying", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try{
                    Intent intent = null;
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,url2);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Add Error", e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Then in the next activity, i am capturing the url and saving it in a static variable from main activity. But while again clicking the button, it should open a browser with the url passed. but instead i am getting an error, activtitynotfound to handle the intent.

```
public class getURL extends Activity{

    EditText text1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
        text1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);

    }


    public void addBookMark(View v){

        String text = text1.getText().toString();
        text1.setText(" ");
        text = String.format("\"http://"+text+"\"");
        MainActivity.url1=text; 
        MainActivity.check=false;

    }
```

Comment: what's the use of String.format here ?

Comment: It will add "http:// to the start of the value entered by user and " at the end of the value.Suppose user enters www.google.com then this format will change it to "http://www.google.com"

Comment: Got the answer finally. I was making a silly mistake.I did the below change and it worked. text = String.format("\"http://"+text+"\""); changed to text = String.format("http://"+text);

Comment: this is not a formatting, this is a concatenation. `text = "http://" + text;` is sufficient

Comment: Agreed njzk and thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer finally. I was making a silly mistake.I did the below change and it worked. text = String.format("\"http://"+text+"\""); changed to text = String.format("http://"+text);